# How to find owner of contract deployer on etherscan website

Tags: contract-development, transactions, metamask, contract-design, etherscan

https://etherscan.io/address/0x6cfa7561bbf940ab4b5c0507d4c9e45c68552b1b

On the Etherscan website, where or how do i navigate to the deployer wallet of this contract? Apparently if i look closely at the deployer wallet i can see him set wallets to "can't sell".[image]

Someone sent me a screenshot of the deployer wallet address as you can see in screenshot starts with 0x9336391c... I just don't know where or how to navigate the deployer wallet on the site.

Also another screenshot where i was shown the contract owner was setting wallets to can't sell, how do i determine or figure that out on Etherscan? Sorry for the noob questions.

[image]

Comment: Etherscan link you have provided "https://etherscan.io/address/0x6cfa7561bbf940ab4b5c0507d4c9e45c68552b1b" is wallet address not contract address. Share the contract address to check further

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, here's the contract address: 0x2a6e1d36bcdc3acc001c50d8646efb246fb3652c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the deployer address in etherscan
here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/R50sN.png

Deployer : https://etherscan.io/address/0x6cfa7561bbf940ab4b5c0507d4c9e45c68552b1b

Comment: thanks dude! I hope you have low gwei transactions forever ❤️